# Bootstrap Col-sm- take effects in Medium devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a code with a class `<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="wrapper-middle">` the problem is when i use a `Medium devices` the `class col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2` take effects and when i remove the `class col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2` my code work correctly  .

This my code as bellow :

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="wrapper-middle">
                <div id="carousel-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                      <div class="item active">
                          <img src="images/carousel/slide1.png" alt="Error picture">
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                          <img src="images/carousel/slide1.png" alt="Error picture">
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                          <img src="images/carousel/slide1.png" alt="Error picture">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>

              </div> 
              <div id="words">
                  <header>
                      <h2><u>Lipsum</u></h2>
                  </header>
                  <article>
                      <div>
                          <p>
                              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>

                      </div>
                  </article>

              </div>    

          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap `col-` classes take effect at all screen sizes greater than the size specified -- i.e. `col-sm-8` will be used at `sm`, `md`, and `lg` unless overridden.